# How to get list of all valid folder and file characters for Windows file system paths in .Net

Tags: .net, windows, file-io, character

`System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` gives list of invalid characters.

But I need to have list of all valid characters.

First and simple idea that comes into mind is to iterate from 0 to 255 and exclude invalid ones, but would it give only valid characters ? Also what about Unicode ? Should I iterate from 0 to 65535 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is nothing in .NET for getting this information.

You could look at the following microsoft page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Relevant excerpt:

```
Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters
in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:

    The following reserved characters:

        < (less than)  
        > (greater than)
        : (colon)
        " (double quote)
        / (forward slash)
        \ (backslash)
        | (vertical bar or pipe)
        ? (question mark)
        * (asterisk)

    Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.

    Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31,
    except for alternate data streams where these characters are allowed.

    Any other character that the target file system does not allow.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
    private static IEnumerable<char> GetValidFileNameChars()
    {
        var invalidChars = new List<char>(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars());
        var allChars = new List<char>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        {
            allChars.Add((char) i);
        }

        var validChars = allChars.AsEnumerable().Except(invalidChars.AsEnumerable());
        return validChars;
    }
```

Alternately, you could iterate from 0 to 65535 (`char.MinValue` to `char.MaxValue`).